# Changing my PROMPT_COMMAND adds a new line

Tags: terminal, bash, iterm2

I've added the following line to my `~/.bashrc` file to change my tab title:

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -e "\033];My Machine\007"'`

After I source the file, my prompt adds a new, blank line after every command. For example:

```
user machine ~:> pwd
/a/path/whatever

user machine ~:>
```

I don't want that third, blank line to be there. I've tested sourcing my `.bashrc` with and without the `PROMPT_COMMAND` line and I know this is the offending line. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to me that you *actually* want to change `PS1`: `export PS1="My Machine \W:> "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -en "\033];My Machine\007"'`

Answer (score 1):

The band-aid fix is to use `echo -en` if your `echo` supports that (suppress the newline).

I don't think it is necessary to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` here, you can just prepend it to your `PS1`:

```
PS1="\[\033]0;My Machine\007\007\]$PS1"
```

The `\[ \]` make sure that the width of what's between them doesn't throw off the line length count.

There are predefined escape sequences so you don't have to hard code the machine name, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt). For example this

```
PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
```

uses `\e` and `\a` instead of `\033`\ and `\007` for escape and bell, and sets the tab title to `user@hostname: currentdir`.

See also the [relevant section in the Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html) and the  [Xterm title HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Xterm-Title.html).

Comment: Why `PS1` over `PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: It's simpler and doesn't have to execute a command for each new prompt...?

Comment: My choice of `PROMPT_COMMAND` relates to another issue I had: http://superuser.com/questions/1073607/source-by-bashrc-when-i-exit-an-ssh-session

Comment: @smilebomb I you absolutely require `PROMPT_COMMAND`, then just using `-en` should fix your problem.